# Storing logs on server while running an android application

Tags: android, logging

I want to know if there is any library available which I can use to record logs on the local machine and uploading them on the server at regular intervals like a week or a month? Please help

Comment: i dont think you need a "specific" library. You could store the logs in an internal SQLite database of the android app and use a background service to send the data to your server with the interval you defined. For this last job you could try with an IntentService or a SyncAdapter

Answer (score 1):

You can store your logs in your device like following,

```
File filename = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/mylog.log"); 
filename.createNewFile(); 
String cmd = "logcat -d -f"+filename.getAbsolutePath();
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

Now you can maintain an AlarmManager or Service to periodically read and send the logs to your server.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is Log mechanism in Android which let print Log's.To print Log's you can Use 
`Log.d(TAG,"Here is Your Log Message");`

First put this log in String like this

```
String logging= String.valueOf(Log.d(TAG,"Message Data "));
```

Then send to server and to write to local file use **AsyncTask**

Whenever Log's statement calls,Calls AsyncTask to run background task for storing logs into server and local disk

To write to local disk consider suggested method by @fluffyBatman